# How can I download free videos from youtube or any other site with Python, without an external video downloader?

Tags: python, video, youtube, python-requests, byte

### Problem

Hi! Most answers refer to using `pytube` when using Python. ***But the problem is that pytube doesn't work for many videos on youtube now.*** It's outdated, and I always get errors. I also want to be able to get other free videos from other sites that are not on youtube.

And I know there are free sites and paid programs that let you put in a url, and it'll download it for you. ***But I want to understand the process of what's happening.***

The following code works for easy things. Obviously it can be improved, but let's keep it super simple...

```
import requests

good_url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4'

bad_url = 'https://r2---sn-vgqsknes.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1585432044&ei=jHF_XoXwBI7PDv_xtsgN&ip=12.345.678.99&id=743bcee1c959e9cd&itag=244&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C298%2C299%2C302%2C303&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=1w&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-vgqsknes%2Csn-ab5szn7z&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=23&pcm2=yes&initcwndbps=3728750&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=22135843&dur=283.520&lmt=1584701992110857&mt=1585410393&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&beids=9466588&c=WEB&txp=5511222&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cpcm2%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ADKhkGMwRgIhAI3WtBFTf4kklX4xl859U8yzqavSzu-2OEn8tvHPoqAWAiEAlSDPhPdb5y4xPxPoXJFCNKr-h2c4jxKU8sAaaxxa7ok%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ABSNjpQwRQIhAJkFK4xhfLraysF13jSZpHCoklyhJrwLjNSCQ1v7IzeXAiBLpVpYf72Gp-dlvwTM2tYzMcVl4Axzm2ARd7fN1gPW-g%3D%3D&alr=yes&cpn=EvFJNwgO-zNQOWkz&cver=2.20200327.05.01&ir=1&rr=12&fexp=9466588&range=15036316-15227116&rn=14&rbuf=0'

r = requests.get(good_url, stream=True)

with open('my_video.mp4', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(r.content)
```

This works. But when I want a youtube video *(and I obviously can't use a regular youtube url because the document request is different from the video request)*...

### Steps taken

1. I'll check the network tab in the dev tools, and it's all filled with a bunch of xhr requests. The headers for them always have the very long url for the request, `accept-ranges: bytes`, and `content-type: video/webm`, or something similar for mp4, etc.
2. Then I'll copy the url for that xhr, change the file extension to the correct one, and run the program.

### Result

Sometimes that downloads a small chunk of the video with no sound *(few seconds long)*, and other times it will download a bigger chunk but with no image. But I want the entire video with sound.

### Question

*Can someone please help me understand how to do this, and explain what's happening, whether it's on another site or youtube??*

Why does `good_url` work, but not `bad_url`??? I figured it might be a timeout thing, so I got that xhr, and immediately tested it from python, but still no luck.

### A related question *(don't worry about answering this one, unless required)*...

Sometimes youtube has `Blob` urls in the html too, example: `<video src='blob:https://www.youtube.com/f4484c06-48ed-4531-a6ee-6a3ae0291d26'>`...

I've read various answers for what blobs are, and I'm not understanding it, because it looks to me like a blob url is doing an xhr to change a url in the DOM, as if it was trying to do the equivalent of an internal redirect on a webserver for a private file that would be served based on view/object level permissions. Is that what's happening? Cause I don't see the point, especially when these videos are free? The way I've done that, such as with lazy loading, is to have a `data-src` attribute with the correct value, and an `onload` event handler runs a function switching the `data-src` value to the `src` value.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAvr5_EtOnI

from this bad_url remove &range=3478828-4655264

try this code:

```py
import requests

good_url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4'

bad_url = 'https://r1---sn-gvcp5mp5u5-q5js.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1631119417&ei=2ZM4Yc33G8S8owPa1YiYDw&ip=42.0.7.242&id=o-AKG-sNstgjok92lJp_o4pF_iJ2MWD4skzEvFcTLl8LX8&itag=396&aitags=133,134,135,136,137,160,242,243,244,247,248,278,394,395,396,397,398,399&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=gB&mm=31,29&mn=sn-gvcp5mp5u5-q5js,sn-i3belney&ms=au,rdu&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=24&initcwndbps=82500&vprv=1&mime=video/mp4&ns=mh_mFY1G7qq0apTltxepCQ8G&gir=yes&clen=7874090&dur=213.680&lmt=1600716258020131&mt=1631097418&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373,24007246&beids=9466586&c=WEB&txp=5531432&n=Q3AfqZKoEoXUzw&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,aitags,source,requiressl,vprv,mime,ns,gir,clen,dur,lmt&lsparams=mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl,initcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgYZMQz5Tc2kucxFsorprl-3e4mCxJ3lpX1pbX-HnFloACIQD-CuHGtUeWstPodprweaA4sUp8ZikyxySZp1m3zlItKg==&alr=yes&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIhAJZg4q9vLal64LO6KAyWkpY1T8OTlJRd9wNXrgDpNOuQAiB77lqm4Ka9uz2CAgrPWMSu6ApTf5Zqaoy5emABYqCB_g==&cpn=5E-Sqvee9UG2ZaNQ&cver=2.20210907.00.00&rn=19&rbuf=90320'

r = requests.get(good_url, stream=True)

with open('my_video.mp4', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I facepalmed for missing such as obvious url parameter *(range)*. But now only the full video downloads. No sound. Any ideas?